# Using capacity share instead of quantity market share in demand estimation (BLP)

Tags: econometrics, supply-and-demand

If I were to use capacity share (as a proxy of quantity market share) in a demand estimation setup (such as BLP), are there ways to deal or interpret the measurement error? I would consider this question answered if someone could point to a paper in which something similar was made.